# run a program from a windows service

Tags: windows, vb.net, windows-services, external

I have a program which i want to invoke from windows service.

```
xsftp.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("c:\stage\psftp.exe", "testuser@X.X.X.X -b c:\stage\script.bat -pw XXX")
xsftp.Start()
```

The same code works fine if i write in a console application, but from windows service it wont run, i see the psftp is being started in the task manager but it wont do anything..

any ideas ?
Thanks!
Srin

Comment: What version of windows is this on?

Comment: any help please ? I'm still trying to find the ans..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you determine it doesn't do anything? If you're looking for GUI, it might be running under a different user, without access to your desktop.

Comment: the script.bat has a ftp commands to put the file to server. I dont see any file on the server. and the last command is 'bye' so technically it should have exited after execution. -- this is what it happens when i run the same code from console app.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need this.. but you need to set the UseShellExecute to false:

```
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
```

I was having the same problem and couldn't find an answer anyway, but I looked into my old code and found the answer :)

Good luck